# C# Cannot convert from void to bool - CS1503

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a small program to act as a stopwatch as part of a course.
The issue I am having is that when I try to compile I am getting  `Cannot convert from void to bool` on my `Duration()` method in my `Program.cs` class.
The method should return `TimeSpan`

I can't see where it is being set to `void`. Maybe something lower level in the C# runtime? Not sure.

`Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Stopwatch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stopwatch = new StopWatchController();
            stopwatch.Start();
            stopwatch.Start(); // Second Start() method should throw an exception
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Duration()); // Error appears here
        }
    }
}
```

`StopwatchController.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Stopwatch
{
    public class StopWatchController
    {
        private DateTime _startTime;
        private DateTime _finishTime;
        private TimeSpan _duration;
        private bool _isWatchRunning;

        public void Start()
        {
            if (!_isWatchRunning)
            {
                _isWatchRunning = !_isWatchRunning;
                _startTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("InvalidArgumentException");
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _isWatchRunning = false;
            _finishTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void Duration() // I'm an idiot
        {
            _duration = _finishTime - _startTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duration() is a void method, but you try to WriteLine it. That won't work well.

Comment: Do you mean "public TimeSpan Duration()" ?

Comment: You must be going code blind :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Duration` should return `TimeSpan` to be used in `Console.WriteLine`:

```
    public TimeSpan Duration()
    {
        return _duration = _finishTime - _startTime;
    }

    ...

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Duration());
```

Comment: There is no point to keep and set `_duration` though, as it's never used.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Can't believe I missed that. Obviously that was going to return void! Thanks.

Comment: As a note, if the original exception mention converting from void to bool, it's because it searches for the first (alphabetically) method signature of Console.WriteLine (since it doesn't have one for a `void` parameter), which takes a `bool`.

Comment: @Shautieh: I think that implementation is *in progress* and thus `_duration` can be used in future; that's the reason I've preserved it.